# How to replace text in regex by using "POSIX" regex

Tags: php, regex, posix-ere, ereg-replace

I have existing code doing in PCRE method and  I would like to have same function in POSIX.
Below is my example code did in PCRE.

```
<?php

$regex = "/(\d)/";
$content = "In the garden have dog,cat,23242,rabbit.";

echo preg_replace($regex,"<span style='color:green'>$1</span>",$content);
//Result:
//In the garden have dog,cat,<span style='color:green'>2</span><span style='color:green'>3</span><span style='color:green'>2</span><span style='color:green'>4</span><span style='color:green'>2</span>,rabbit.
```

I'm trying doing the samething in POXIS but unable to get the same output.
Below is my example code did in POSIX.;

```
<?php

$regex = "([[:digit:]])";
$content = "In the garden have dog,cat,23242,rabbit."

echo ereg_replace($regex,"<span style='color:green'>$1</span>",$content);
//Result:
//In the garden have dog,cat,<span style='color:green'>$1</span><span style='color:green'>$1</span><span style='color:green'>$1</span><span style='color:green'>$1</span><span style='color:green'>$1</span>,rabbit.
```

Comment: Why do you need `ereg` if you can do all you need with `preg_*`? Well, to make the `ereg` function work the same, just replace `$1` with `\\1` in the replacement string.

Comment: A integrate system I using is only read posix. Thank for your answer, is work.

Comment: POSIX mode (all ereg_* functions) are deprecated since php 5.3. Please don't use them. They are completely removed from php 7.0

Comment: You can use posix with `preg_replace`, you also can use a quantifier and replace all the numbers at once, or do you mean to replace them one at a time? https://3v4l.org/l069J without the quantifier you get multiple spans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that [`ereg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ereg-replace.php),

> This function was DEPRECATED in PHP 5.3.0, and REMOVED in PHP 7.0.0.

If your PHP environemnt does not support `preg_replace`, use the current code with `\\1` instead of `$1` in the replacement pattern.

```
$regex = "([[:digit:]]+)";
$content = "In the garden have dog,cat,23242,rabbit.";
echo ereg_replace($regex,"<span style='color:green'>\\1</span>",$content);
// => In the garden have dog,cat,<span style='color:green'>23242</span>,rabbit.
```